# Assign new or update instances in Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of alerts I'm receiving an update of this array in an observable, but **I don't want replace the array instance** I want to update **each** position in the array.

**Interface**

```
export interface Alert {
    id: number;
    tester: string;
    part_number: string;
    handler: string;    
    issue: string;
}
```

**Component**

```
...
alerts: Alert[] = [];
...
this.alertRepository.getAlertsData().subscribe(res =>{
            this.alerts[]= res;
        });
```

I'm looking for the best approach to do it given an array with min 200 rows.

Comment: Why don't you want to replace the array?

Comment: use spread operator `this.alerts = [...res]` it will make change detection happy :-)

Comment: Because I'm using a data-table and I'm filtering and sorting but when I receive new information every 2 min  the data table get default filter, sorting and pagination position. I not wanted mentioned because the question  is going to get another sense. I know what happen with the data table and it is receiving another array instance.

Comment: @mumair do you have more information about it?

Comment: yes basically when you are assigning array like `this.alerts = res` then reference remains same. If you change the reference by spread operator. here is very good explanation https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/immutable/what_is_immutability.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a problem related to immutability I want update each alert instance inside of array alerts without modifying the array instance.

Comment: use `trackBy` if performance is a concern.

Comment: Thanks @Vikas but I have not access to the iterator  because I'm  using [ng2-smart-table](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table) I just have access to an `@Input()`